# Wordpress Permalink Problem 404

Tags: redirect

My website old permalink `http://example.com/postid.html` . Now I changed my permalink structure to `http://example.com/postname` .

My old link which is now 404.

I tried using Yoast Generator and redirect plugin for `.htaccess` code for 301 redirect and updated my `.htaccess` but the problem not solved yet.

May I know how can I 301 redirect all my  Old post `postid.html` to new post `postname`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of googling, I myself sorted out.

Just add the following line in your .htacess

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(\d+).html$ http://sitename.com/?p=$1